# How to freeze versions of subspecs of Cococapods' Podfile

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods, xcode-server

The root of my problem begins when I want Xcode Server to bump a version and push the changes to the remote repo. I'm using fastlane for that which is integrated in a post-integration script. The 'commit_version_bump' action of fastlane fails because there are other changes (Podfile.lock) than the Info.plist files modified by the version bump.

All pods in the Podfile are fixed like this:

**Podfile**

```
...
pod 'sample', '1.0.0'
...
```

However, the Podfile.lock changes when new versions for the sub pods are available and the sub specs aren't fixed (`~> 1.0`).

**Podfile.lock**

```
...
  - sample (1.0.0)
    - subSample (~> 1.0)
...
```

I have no control over the sub pods, i guess. I just want the Xcode Server to use exactly the same pods including sub pods that i use on my development machine.

So, is there some way to fix the subspecs?